# Could not connect to Database with JAVAFX and Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, javafx

I am creating loginsystem to login to oracle db using java fx. I am running into 2 problems here, 1. I cant make connection to DB 2. I am not sure i am putting the ojdbc jar into the right place.

so my code is,
Util/ConnectionDB.java

```
package Util;

import java.sql.*;
/**
 * Created by engineering09 on 12/3/2015.
 */

public class ConnectionDB {

    private static final String DB_USER = "WELTESMIN";
    private static final String DB_PASS = "123pass";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "WEN";

    public boolean openConnection(){
        boolean result;

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection conn = null;

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:"+DB_NAME+"",DB_USER,DB_PASS);

            if (conn != null){
                System.out.println("CONNECTION DONE");
            }
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and the main,

```
package Controller;

import Util.ConnectionDB;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../View/login.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Weltes Oxygen Management");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
        testConnection();
    }

    public void testConnection(){
        ConnectionDB connect = new ConnectionDB();
        connect.openConnection();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: Project Sctructure]

Please help me, this is my error msg

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could
>   not establish the connection  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:254)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
>   Util.ConnectionDB.openConnection(ConnectionDB.java:30)    at
>   Controller.Main.testConnection(Main.java:23)  at
>   Controller.Main.start(Main.java:18)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish
>   the connection    at
>   oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:439)     at
>   oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:454)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:693)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:251)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)    ... 18
>   more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)     at
>   oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)     at
>   oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)

Comment: Check your connection settings first with something that is Javabased too, for example dbVisualizer

Comment: @Marged i tried doing simple one class with main to test this connection in eclipse and import external JAR. It works fine.. I need to do this project in intelliJ